# How to move sprite relative to its original position with touch in spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I looking to move a sprite relative to the player's touch.  I am familiar with the moveTo SKActions, however I am wondering how to implement sprite movement where the sprite moves along with the user's touch movement.

For example, I have a sprite in the centre of the screen. If I apply a touch at the bottom of the screen and move my finger up , the sprite will move up from the centre(it's original position).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var node = SKSpriteNode()
    var nodePosition = CGPoint()
    var startTouch = CGPoint()


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        // node set up
        node = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        node.position = CGPoint.zero
        self.addChild(node)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let location = touch?.location(in: self){
            startTouch = location
            nodePosition = node.position
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let location = touch?.location(in: self){
            node.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:  nodePosition.x + location.x - startTouch.x, y: nodePosition.y + location.y - startTouch.y), duration: 0.1))
        }
    }

}
```